# Why are there gaps between the elements in this unordered list?

Tags: html, css

For some reason there are horizontal gaps between the `<li>` elements in [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/8acpf2jt/), and I simply cannot fathom why they are there.

**Markup**

```
<ul>
    <li>
        Stuff
    </li>
    <li>
        Things
    </li>
    <li>
        /dev/null
    </li>
    <li>
        Use Jquery!
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  height:50px;
}
ul > li {
  display:inline-block;
  background-color:silver;
  height:100%;
  width:20%;
  max-width:300px;
  list-style-type:none;
  text-align:center;
    line-height:50px;
}
```

What is causing these gaps?

```css
ul {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  height:50px;
}
ul > li {
  display:inline-block;
  background-color:silver;
  height:100%;
  width:20%;
  max-width:300px;
  list-style-type:none;
  text-align:center;
    line-height:50px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        Stuff
    </li>
    <li>
        Things
    </li>
    <li>
        /dev/null
    </li>
    <li>
        Use Jquery!
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You mean the whitespaces? Remove the line breaks between each `<li>…</li>`.

Comment: @Xufox Whoa, that worked! Why does whitespace in the html source affect the output?

Comment: There were no whitespaces at that point in the HTML source. Line breaks cause this. I don’t know why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are whitespaces generated by the line breaks in the HTML source.

Remove them like so:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        Stuff
    </li><li>
        Things
    </li><li>
        /dev/null
    </li><li>
        Use Jquery!
    </li>
</ul>
```

or put comments between them:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        Stuff
    </li><!--
    --><li>
        Things
    </li><!--
    --><li>
        /dev/null
    </li><!--
    --><li>
        Use Jquery!
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

Add

```
float:left;
```

to `ul > li` to remove the gap.

```css
ul {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  height:50px;
}
ul > li {
  display:inline-block;
  background-color:silver;
  height:100%;
  width:20%;
  max-width:300px;
  list-style-type:none;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:50px;
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        Stuff
    </li>
    <li>
        Things
    </li>
    <li>
        /dev/null
    </li>
    <li>
        Use Jquery!
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer doing like this:
https://jsfiddle.net/8acpf2jt/1/

```
ul {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  height:50px;
}
ul > li {
  display:block;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
  background-color:silver;
  height:100%;
  width:20%;
  max-width:300px;
  list-style-type:none;
  text-align:center;
    line-height: 3em;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

so, I think padding was the deal and display type.

Comment: update: why do you need height for ul? I removed it because it doesn't needed: https://jsfiddle.net/8acpf2jt/2/

Comment: Removing the `margin`, `padding`, and `display` declarations from your fiddle doesn't seem to change anything; what's actually fixing the gap is `float:left`.

Comment: I did that because sometimes it can inherit these things from somewhere declared above.